# Gzip/ungzip a file for read (xcode 6, swift)

Tags: swift, gzip, xcode6

I have link to gzip file (with json). Requires to download it, ungzip and read it. I've found many articles about json parsers, but can't find any information about gzip. Use Xcode 6 and Swift.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add libz.dylib to your build (already built in to Mac OS X and iOS), and read the [zlib documentation](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html).